# Ionic 3 *ngIf doesn't update the view

Tags: ionic3, angular-ng-if

I'm working with Ionic 3. I change the value of a variable in a component and the view of the page is not updated.

I have looked at the answers to similar questions but I have not re-solved the problem.

My Code.

Home.html

```
    <div *ngIf="getLoading()" text-center>
    <img src="http://spcdn1.whichairline.com/1c40c0f0542d7227719eccd99bd71fd172d36e0a/images/loaders/loader-search.gif">
    <h1><span>Loading...</span></h1></div>
<component-myList></component-myList>
```

home.ts

```
constructor(
public navCtrl: NavController,
public myList: myListComponent) {}

public getLoading() {
  return this.myList.loading;
}
```

myList.ts

```
    @Component({
       selector: 'component-myList',
       templateUrl: 'myList.html'
    })



export class myListComponent {

  public loading: boolean = false;

  constructor() {}

  putLoading() {
    this.loading = !this.loading;
    console.log(this.loading);
  }
}
```

myList.html

```
<button color="secondary" (click)="putLoading()" ion-button right>Put Loading</button>
```

I click the button but nothing happens ... although I do see that the loading value changes.

Any ideas?

Comment: are these components nested i mean parent child relation is there between them or are they two separate components

Comment: Sorry, I forgot put the code: <component-myList></component-myList> in the question. Home is a Page and myList is a component.

Comment: Ok then you need to emit events so that the change is detected inside the parent component

Comment: Ok, i'll check de events use. Thanks

Comment: If you want help I can answer and then you can easily implement it

Comment: Thanks Mahesh! I solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved it with events thanks to Mahesh Jadhav...

I have created in the home's constructor:

```
events.subscribe ('update', loading => {
   this.loadingLocal = loading;
});
```

And in the component's constructor:

```
events.publish ("update", this.loading, 1);
```

Each time I modify the load value in the component, I call the event:

```
events.publish ("update", this.loading, 1);
```

And so the page finds out and renders again ...